# Python - Downloading PDF's contained in a JQueryFileTree

Tags: python, jquery, selenium, web-scraping, download

I'm creating a file downloaded to automatically download PDF's from a website related to my employer's company.

It looks like the PDF's are contained within a JQueryFileTree. Is there a way I can download one of the folders below and save it to disk along with it's content PDF's?

I'm using Python and selenium thus far to automate the logging in etc.

Thanks

My code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 

import secrets

class manual_grabber():
    """ A class creating a manual downloader for the Roger Technology website """
    def __init__(self):
        """ Initialize attributes of manual grabber """
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('\\Users\\Joel\\Desktop\\Python\\manual_grabber\\chromedriver.exe')

    def login(self):
        """ Function controlling the login logic """
        self.driver.get('urltosite')

        sleep(1)

        # Locate elements and enter login details
        user_in = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/form/input[6]')
        user_in.send_keys(secrets.username)   

        pass_in = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/form/input[7]')
        pass_in.send_keys(secrets.password)

        enter_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/form/div/input')
        enter_button.click()
        
        # Click Self Service Area button
        self_service_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"]/ul/li[1]/a')
        self_service_button.click()


grab = manual_grabber()
grab.login()
```

The file structure is this:
[image]

When clicking on one of these folders, it opens the content PDF's in the window to the right of the tree.

And the DOM:
[image]

Comment: Hi, Can you please share your code so far, the DOM structure and how you would go about manually downloading a folder from such a display?

Comment: @RichEdwards Hi, I've edited my question showing the file structure etc. You are unable to download a folder directly manually. You can download each individual file by clicking on the download button on the right hand side. Hope this helps.

Comment: Selenium will do what you can do - how would you download the files?  - i assume click the tree on the left then click the download button on the right?  - ... for selenium, identify the tree item (by text if possible), use find_elements (plural) for all `a` that match your criteria and loop though to download all  - or use a library like libcurl to control the downloads from the href as downloading from sleneium is "uncontrolled" (i.e. no ida of progress) - if you can share the DOM from devtools for each of the stages i can help you with identifiers, otherwise pseudo is a far as i can go

Comment: @RichEdwards Thanks for that. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @RichEdwards After trying to use the .click() function on the left tree it tells me it cannot find element. Is this because it is contained inside of a JQueryFileTree or does it not matter?

Comment: it depends what you're identifier is and what the DOM looks like. If your page is slow and script based it might need a webdriverwait to wait for it to be ready, if you have the wrong identifier then you'll need to find the right, unique identifier :-)

Comment: @RichEdwards How would I find the DOM and the right unique identifier please?

Comment: F12 to open devtools, select the element tab - that's the document object model - and use the identifiers tool (top left button) to find what you want... You can then copy the xpath/vss or try and write your own. You might be able to use something like //*[text() ='Barrier'] (which might select that barrier tree item)... If you can share that dom structure I can help more :-)

Comment: @RichEdwards Updated the question to contain the DOM. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: You'll need to use the select tool (icon in the top left corner of devtools) and click on an element in the page in order drill down to that elemet's detail.  Alternatively, you can learn how this all works with some light videos : https://testautomationu.applitools.com/web-element-locator-strategies/chapter1.html

Comment: @RichEdwards Done, updated with element specific DOM. I'll take a look at the videos also.

Comment: Thanks for the dom. It typically works better as text (not image) but it's enough to to see the bits I need. I'm on my phone at the mo but I'll report back in a few hours  (probably delete this comment when I do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the DOM and the screenshots your will be able to select from your jquery tree.

you can use this xpath the select from the tree on the left:

```
//a[.//nobr[text()='Products catalogue and brouches']]
```

For this xpath:

- `//a` is a relative `a`  (anywhere on the page)
- starting  a `[` means we identify it with...
- `.` a child from this location (i.e. beneath the `a`)
- `//nobr` any nobr tag
- where the `text()` = 'Products catalogue and brochures'  (case sensitive)

In short, it's any `a` that has a child `nobr` which has the text we want.

I threw this in  simple page and it unique matches the output:

[image: demo of correct path found]

There are a lot more xpath identifiers and approaches - [this is great learning resource](https://testautomationu.applitools.com/web-element-locator-strategies/chapter1.html).

Hopefully with that xpath you can just enter the text you want to click and it will do it for you.

If your identifiers aren't found - please let me know and i'll look again.

---

Some bonus thoughts for q1:

DEPENDING on your application, and how the tree works, you might need [a wait strategy](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

There are 2 major approaches, explicit and implicit. For the sake of simplicity (as this answer is long enough already), try an implicit wait first:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

set that ONCE in your `__init__` and selenium will wait up to 10 seconds before complaining about non existent objects.  (if it doesn't work, let me know!)

You might also need to scroll your tree to bring the element into view. In which case, try this - just identify your element with the xpath above and pass it into here:

```py
def ScrollIntoView(element):
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

---

The next part of your question is downloading files. Clicking the links on the right.

You'll need to share more of the DOM - if you can share 2 or 3 of those `a`'s or 'img''s that initiate the download i'll be able to provide a bespoke response.

In **general terms**, if you want to get "all" the links to download you'll need to do something like:

```py
#get all the elements - needs a condition that identifies just these anchors
allLinks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(some condition)

#loop through all links and action the click
for link in allLinks:
    link.click()
    time.sleep(3) # don't download too many at once - depending on their size let them complete
```

File downloading in selenium is possible, but you can't get your download size, progress or speed. Essentially you're blind to it once it kicks off.

There are alternatives but they ramp up the complexity.

Keep me posted with the extra DOM stuff if you need more help. Happy to look more and provide more support.

---

Update from the comments below.
To manage iframes you need to identify it and switch to it  in order to do your actions.
I cannot test the xpath - so give it a go and update it as you need.

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src,"ManageFiles")]')
driver._switch_to.frame(frame)
#do the actions on the frame
#when ready...
driver._switch_to.default_content()
```

At the end, be sure to switch back to your default content or to the next iframe that needs interacting with.

---

Switch, find and click with waits:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//iframe[contains(@src,"ManageFiles")]')))

#Watch spelling and case on this line
myListObject = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[.//nobr[text()='Products catalogue and brochures']]")))

myListObject.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I use the xpath you gave it I get an invalid syntax error. When I remove the quotation marks surrounding the text I want to click it works but when it gets to the part it has to click it just doesn't click.

Comment: The joys of not being able to test out code before i try it :-)    -  first check this finds an element:  `element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.//nobr[text()='Products catalogue and brochures']]")`   - watching out for any spelling mistakes in the Text()  - i couldn't copy and paste and int he above i typed "brouches"  (not brochures)

Comment: if that finds the element, but you cannot do `element.click()` - you can try this as a plan b `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)`   ... If i had access to your site i would have tried all this for you and tested it all out

Comment: Just tried this. The xpath doesn't find the element. I suspect this is because it is inside of a container and Query tree. Is there a piece of code I need to first enter into the container/query tree before looking? @RichEdwards

Comment: are there `frames` or `iframes` present? (they need special handling)  - you probably already did but check the spelling or try for another tree item you can see - and, if you haven't already. give the xpath a go in devtools to see if that finds it :-)

Comment: Yes, there are iframes present. This is the line: `<iframe> src="/staff/ManageFiles/Explore.asp?idLingua=15" name="fExplore" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>`

Comment: Update added with some sample code to the end of handling frames with selenium

Comment: Thanks, been trying this for the last few days and still struggling. I've updated the question to include the full DOM. It still isn't finding the element. Any advice? @RichEdwards

Comment: @j4yman It's diffiicult from an image - typically it's a trial and error process to fine tune the xpaths and waits. I've added another new section at the bottom that incorporates sync  find and click...  If this doesn't work i need to know the error please mate...  And please watch out for spelling and case on the items!  You'll only be able to click if the item is visible so change it to be a higher level item if the tree needs expanding

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'll trial and error and find the issue. Much appreciated.

Comment: @j4yman - a tip: Think what you do manually in order to get to where you want. You need to click to expand the folder path out. Looking again at your DOM most have the class "directory collapsed". If you're not already, click each level on the tree in order to make sure it is expanded before selecting the final item. It might be in the DOM but it needs to be visible to be accessible.... start small, and create a script that click clicks the top level that's visible by default, then add each layer as you get used to it

Comment: Just to let you know, I managed to get this working yesterday. I deleted all my function and rewrote and it worked. Thanks so much for your help and time! @RichEdwards